# How to fix bootstrap breadcrump-items with broken height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to make breadcrumb line using bootstrap and `thymeleaf` but it has this strange broken height in it.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsMIz.png)

**CODE**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <!--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">-->
    <div class="navbar-nav container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb mr-auto">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a th:href="@{/account/notebooks}">
                    <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                    Notebooks
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a th:href="@{'/notebook/{notebookId}/edit' (notebookId=${notebook.id})}">
                    <div th:text="${notebook.title}"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" th:if="${currentNote} != null">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" th:text="${currentNote.name}">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How to make it into a straight line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flexbox` for set elements in straight line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <!--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">-->
    <div class="navbar-nav container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb mr-auto">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item d-flex">
                <a th:href="@{/account/notebooks}">
                    <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                    Notebooks
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item d-flex">
                <a th:href="@{'/notebook/{notebookId}/edit' (notebookId=${notebook.id})}">
                    <div th:text="${notebook.title}">Test</div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item d-flex" th:if="${currentNote} != null">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle p-0" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" th:text="${currentNote.name}">Test
                </a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```